# How to I do this using PL/SQL subquery?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to list all products with their highest unit price, i.e. not discounted. How do I do that?

Please run the following scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails 
(OrderID  NUMBER NOT NULL, 
  ProductID  NUMBER NOT NULL, 
  UnitPrice  NUMBER NOT NULL, 
  Quantity  NUMBER NOT NULL, 
  Discount  NUMBER NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT PK_Order_Details 
  PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, ProductID), 
  CONSTRAINT CK_Discount   CHECK ((Discount >= 0 and Discount <= 1)), 
  CONSTRAINT CK_Quantity   CHECK ((Quantity > 0)), 
  CONSTRAINT CK_UnitPrice   CHECK ((UnitPrice >= 0)), 
  CONSTRAINT FK_OrderDetails_Orders FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES 
  Orders(OrderID), 
  CONSTRAINT FK_OrderDetails_Products FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES 
  Products(ProductID)
);

    INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10248, 11, 14.0000, 12, 0);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10248, 42, 9.8000, 10, 0);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10248, 72, 34.8000, 5, 0);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10249, 14, 18.6000, 9, 0);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10249, 51, 42.4000, 40, 0);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10250, 41, 7.7000, 10, 0);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10250, 51, 42.4000, 35, 0.15);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10250, 65, 16.8000, 15, 0.15);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10251, 22, 16.8000, 6, 0.05);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10251, 57, 15.6000, 15, 0.05);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10251, 65, 16.8000, 20, 0);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10252, 20, 64.8000, 40, 0.05);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10252, 33, 2.0000, 25, 0.05);
INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount) VALUES (10252, 60, 27.2000, 40, 0);
```

Comment: Could you post sample data and desired output?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Based on your sample data (ProductID 51 and 65) it seems that the UnitPrice always contains the price before the discount. Just querying the distinct ProductID and UnitPrice would solve your problem. What remains is the issue of inconsistent data (what if one Product has a different UnitPrice on different Orders?), but that is only solved by moving the UnitPrice to the Product table.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
select ProductId, max(UnitPrice) 
from OrderDetails 
group by ProductId
```

or you need this one:

```
select ProductId, max(UnitPrice - Discount) 
    from OrderDetails 
    group by ProductId
```

or , for total sales:

```
select ProductId, 
      max((UnitPrice - Discount)*Quantity) 
        from OrderDetails 
        group by ProductId
```